# Extracting ASCII data from SAP to other systems

Tags: s4hana

We are exporting some data from SAP to Azure. This includes a field containing URL information. SAP stores this in ASCII format.

How this data can be converted to text data in this other system? Is there some standard code/libraries (e.g. Java, Python) available?

More information - when the are seeing data using SAP Logon, it shows as a string "`FF060201.....`" which looks like ASCII Hex. But when I try an online ASCII converter like http://www.unit-conversion.info/texttools/ascii/, it is unable to convert and show the URL (displaying some junk characters). Is this because SAP Logon screen is displaying the data different way whereas actual ASCII data stored in different?

Thanks in advance for any pointers/ help.

Regards,

S. Das

Edit:

This is how I am searching the table using SAP Logon, and seeing the data (stored in the column named Data)

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's not related to ASCII at all, and anyway S/4HANA does use Unicode characters. The string you obtained is some data compressed by a SAP-owned compression algorithm. Can't help more without more details.

Comment: hi @SandraRossi, thank you for your answer. How can we perform reverse compression to get back the original url string, using another programming language/platform e.g. Java, .Net or Python?  what other details is needed for that?

Comment: I don't understand at all what you exactly did, what you explain doesn't seem related to the string `FF060201.....` you get, so I prefer to be sure. Please clarify all the details about how you "are exporting some data from SAP to Azure", and how/where you "are seeing data using SAP Logon..." (data being `FF060201.....`), it's something that I absolutely don't understand... Add screenshots please, etc.

Comment: Hello @SandraRossi. apologies for the confusion. I do not have much SA technical knowledge and thought it might be standard. I added some screenshots above to show how I am using SAP Logon to see the data in question. As per some SAP developer, this is stored in ASCII format. But that may not be correct; as you mentioned it may be some SAP compression.

Comment: Also for exporting data from SAP to Azure, a replication tool is planned. But that is not relevant here. For this question, we can simply assume that this SAP table and  data stored in it is replicated in Azure. What I am trying to find out is how to "decrypt" this data to get the original URL it represents.

Comment: Thanks. So, I confirmed it's compressed data. You can only decompress it using ABAP. For `STXL`, you may call the function `RFC_READ_TEXT` to decompress it if you can install an SAP RFC protocol library (PyRFC for Python, JCO for Java, Netweaver RFC SDK and so on).

Comment: Hi @SandraRossi. Thanks so much. Unfortunately that is not possible. We are using Jco and PyRFC for other situations where directly interfacing with SAP, But here the reason we are exporting data to Azure is to build a data lake and provide this data  to al different consumers through an API. If the API has to call SAP function to decrypt the data for this field, then base purpose is lost. So I am looking for some equivalent mechanism to perform the decompression in Azure. Does SAP support any java/python/other form for such decompression on other non-SAP platforms?

Comment: Could you explain which technology you currently use to read the data? SAP GUI Scripting? If so, you may run the function module `READ_TEXT` by using the transaction code `SE37`.

Comment: Hi @SandraRossi , reading the data within SAP is not an issue, READ_TEXT works fine for that. The problem now is really how to read the same data in an environment outside SAP, after the data is exported. This export is a file/object level copy using a replication tool. So the data is available in exact same format/encoding outside SAP in Azure (it could be any other public cloud).  Now since this particular data is encrypted/compressed, we need an equivalent mechanism to "decrypt" it.

Comment: So question  turns out - if SAP applies a compression technique to store a field, how does it support decompression of same using another open technology (non-ABAP, like Java, python, .Net or any programming language or library that can be run on a public cloud).

Comment: I understand your point, but why do you desperately think that SAP provides the SAP proprietary algorithm to decompress this data from outside software, and why can't you just use the SAP proprietary algorithm within SAP. Maybe you can conclude a partnership with SAP? ;-)

Comment: if it is deemed to be a propietary algo then that reverses the lens. in todays world its a lock in issue, but yes SAP still does that :) but i agree, then only option remains is perform this decryption before exporting data out of SAP (which is going to be a big task to pursue).  
Thank you very much Sandra for the insghts; it has been a great help.